# How to find elements inside this div structure in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the below div structure,

```
 <div id=gridRows">
      <ul class = "itemRow">
       <li> <input type="hidden" id="hford1" value="1" /> <input type="hidden" id="hfsce1" value="1" /> </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class = "itemRow">
       <li> <input type="hidden" id="hford2" value="2" /><input type="hidden" id="hfsce2" value="2" /></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class = "itemRow">
        <li> <input type="hidden" id="hford3" value="3" /><input type="hidden" id="hfsce3" value="3" /></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class = "itemRow">
        <li> <input type="hidden" id="hford4" value="4" /><input type="hidden" id="hfsce4" value="4" /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

How to iterate this and get the hiddenfield value of each row inside the loop? How can get both the hidden fields values

Comment: IDs must be unique, `id="itemRow"` use class instead

Comment: Invalid structure! you can't wrap elements in `<ul>` directly, Use `<li>`

Answer (score 2):

```
var ar = [];
$('#gridRows ul.itemRow li input').each(function() {
   $ar.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: @scimonster - we can define javascript arrays using  new Array() as well but accepted your edit for the sake of brevity :)

Comment: `new Array()` yes, but `Array()` is improper as far as i know.

Comment: @coderman you will get all the hidden field values in the array ar using this method with the key indicating the serial number of the hidden input in the stack. So you can group the array by even indexes for your answer.

Comment: I didnt get you.. can you please temme how can i fetch both the hfs values?

Comment: the array gets generated as key value pairs - the 0 and 1st key correspond to your first two hidden fields, 2 and 3 to the next 2 and so on. You can group the 2 together into a second level array too if you want. Does that make it clear?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul').each(function()
{
   $(this).value; // This is your rel value
});
```